# Injectivity of $A-\lambda I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I'm reading a paper on determinants and on one point the author states that:

A complex number $\lambda$ is called an eigenvalue of matrix $A$ if $A-\lambda I$ is not injective.

Why is this? Could someone clarify :)

Thank you! =)

Comment: Why? Because that's the definition of eigenvalue. Can you work out what it means?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's view $A$ as a linear operator from vector spaces $V \to W$.  An eigenvalue $\lambda$ and eigenvector $x$ satisfy

$$Ax = \lambda x$$

So equivalently:

$$( A - \lambda I ) x = 0$$

But $( A - \lambda I ) 0 = 0$ and $0 \ne x$.  This shows that $A - \lambda I$ is not injective.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align*}
A-\lambda I\text{ is not injective} & \iff\exists v_{1},v_{2}\colon v_{1}\neq v_{2}\text{ and }(A-\lambda I)v_{1}=(A-\lambda I)v_{2}\\
 & \iff\exists x\colon x\neq0\text{ and }(A-\lambda I)x=0\\
 & \iff A-\lambda I\text{ is singular}\\
 & \iff\det(A-\lambda I)=0
\end{align*}
The last line regarding the determinant is probably the definition
of eigenvalue you are familiar with.